# How to register Authentication Provider for identity in ASP.NET Core 3.1 using a custom service?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identity, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app that uses Identity to authenticate users. I would like to configure Identity to allow external logins from different providers like Facebook and Twitter.

I have multiple external-login-provider stored in a database. These records can be accessed using `IAuthProvider` service.

When the app is configured using the `ConfigureServices()` method, I want to resolve an instance of `IAuthProvider` to get all available records from the database and then add the needed login-providers.

Below is my code I am struggling on how to resolve `IAuthProvider` instance while in the `ConfigureServices()` method. Perhaps there is a better way to configure or defer configure the providers until later but not sure how and where to configure the server.

How can I create an instance of the `IAuthProvider` and correctly configure the Identity providers?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql"));
    });
    services.AddScoped<IAuthProvider, AuthProvider>();
    // other services

    var providers = // Here I somehow need to resolve an instance of IAuthProvider;

    AuthenticationBuilder authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication();

    foreach (var provider in providers.All())
    {
        if (provider.Name == ExternalLoginProvider.Facebook)
        {
            authBuilder.AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = provider.AppId;
                options.AppSecret = provider.Secret;
            });
        }

        if (provider.Name == ExternalLoginProvider.Twitter)
        {
            authBuilder.AddTwitter(options =>
            {
                options.ConsumerKey = provider.AppId;
                options.ConsumerSecret = provider.Secret;
            });
        }
        // Other providers as needed per the records found in the database
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your code has already registered the implementation of IAuthProvider, you can simpply call servcice.GetService() to get an instance of AuthProvider.
I don't get your point of having different authprovider in such a way, according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#multiple-authentication-providers) you can add different auth provider in chain like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions => { ... })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions => { ... })
    .AddTwitter(twitterOptions => { ... })
    .AddFacebook(facebookOptions => { ... });
```

Any reason why adding them seperatly?

**Edit:**

If you just want to get the instance of IAuthProvider, just try

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var provider = serviceProvider.GetService<IAuthProvider>();
```

Comment: The is a valid approach if you want to hardcode the authentication you want to use. In my case, the provider secrets and which providers to use are in the database. I would need to get a list of providers and then register them as per the database configuration